# Is there something wrong with the constructer?

Tags: c++, xcode, class

I'm making this program using a class named `animal`, below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "animal.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    animal moke;
    ofstream out;
    out.open("/Users/Abel/Desktop/Cpp/animal/animal/animalRecords.txt");
    vector<animal> monke;
    bool quit = false;
    
    while (!quit) {
        
        int choice;
        cout << "1. Add info for animals    2. Edit Info for animals    3. Exit\n";
        cin >> choice;
        string nam;
        string spec;
        int ag;
        int editRow;
        //menu
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Enter the Animal's name\n";
                cin >> nam;
                moke.setName(nam);
                cout << "Enter the Species\n";
                cin >> spec;
                moke.setSpecies(spec);
                cout << "Enter the age\n";
                cin >> ag;
                moke.setAge(ag);
                monke.push_back(moke);
                break;
            case 2:
                if(monke.size() == 0) {
                    cout << "Nothing to modify";
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < monke.size(); i++) {
                        cout << i+1 << "\t\tName = " << monke[i].getName() << "\tSpecies = " << monke[i].getSpecies() << "\tAge = " << monke[i].getAge() << endl;
                    }
                    cout << "Which row would you like to edit\n";
                    cin >> editRow;
                    if (editRow > monke.size() || editRow < 1) {
                        cout << "Please follow directions\n";
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "1. Edit name\t2. Edit species\t3. Edit age\n";
                        cin >> choice;
                        switch(choice) {
                            case 1:
                                cout << "Enter the new name\n";
                                cin >> nam;
                                monke[editRow-1].setName(nam);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                cout << "Enter the new species\n";
                                cin >> spec;
                                monke[editRow-1].setSpecies(spec);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                cout << "Enter the new age\n";
                                cin >> ag;
                                monke[editRow-1].setAge(ag);
                                break;
                            default:
                                cout << "You need to learn how to follow instruction <:(\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (monke.size() == 0) {
                    cout << "Bye\n";
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < monke.size(); i++)
                        out << i+1 << "\t\tName = " << monke[i].getName() << "\tSpecies = " << monke[i].getSpecies() << "\tAge = " << monke[i].getAge() << endl;
                }
                break;
            default:
                cout << "You are so basic\n";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class animal{
public:
    animal();
    animal(string name, string species, int age);
    animal(animal &E);
    void setName(string name);
    void setSpecies(string species);
    void setAge(int age);
    string getName();
    string getSpecies();
    int getAge();
private:
    string n, s;
    int a;
};
```

```
#include "animal.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

animal::animal() {
    n = "";
    s = "";
    a = 0;
}

animal::animal(string name, string species, int age) {
    n = name;
    s = species;
    a = age;
}

animal::animal(animal &E) {
    a = E.a;
    s = E.s;
    s = E.s;
}

void animal::setName(string name) {
    n = name;
}

void animal::setSpecies(string species) {
    s = species;
}

void animal::setAge(int age) {
    a = age;
}

string animal::getName() {
    return n;
}

string animal::getSpecies() {
    return s;
}

int animal::getAge() {
    return a;
}
```

When running this, it shows these errors:

[image: error]

```
No matching constructor for initialization of 'animal' 

is_cpp17_move_insertable<std::allocator<animal>, void>::value' "The specified type does not meet the requirements of Cpp17MoveInsertable" 

No matching constructor for initialization of 'animal'
```

Comment: The copy ctor for `animal` doesn't set the name, but sets the species twice. You don't actually appear to need to define a user-defined copy ctor, so you'd probably be better off leaving it out.

Comment: Please paste the text of the error messages verbatim, instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: The thing is i cant see the whole message

Comment: ill try doing it

Comment: No matching constructor for initialization of 'animal'

is_cpp17_move_insertable<std::allocator<animal>, void>::value' "The specified type does not meet the requirements of Cpp17MoveInsertable"

No matching constructor for initialization of 'animal'

Comment: Please add that information as an [edit] to the question, not as a comment.

Comment: I would think there would be a build output window somewhere in the IDE. You should be able to copy and paste the errors from there. But yes, edit the question. Don't post the errors as comments.

Comment: btw, its an error in memory.h

Comment: Looks like wrong signature for `animal` copy ctor is causing an ambiguity or something. Declare it as `animal(const animal&)`, or just get rid of it. The compiler will provide one that works for this class.

Comment: bro, it fixed it

Comment: big shoutout to fred

Comment: so for other programs i didnt use const and it still worked, could you explain whats different here